# Nodejs is unable to pipe the same parse over multiple streams

Tags: node.js, csv, parsing, asynchronous

I'll take this might be an odd questions, but I'm unable to understand what's happening to my code at the moment.
I have a few .csv files with over 100k lines each and I'm using a `createReadStream` to read those files and parse through `csv parse`, if I run this one file at a time, it works flawless, but whenever a run all of them(async btw) seems like the parser get lost after the first .csv file.

Here are some snippets of my code:

```
const parser = parse({
  columns: true,
  delimiter: ',',
  quote: '"',
  cast: (columnValue, context) => {
    if (context.column === 'Cód. Perfil') {
      return parseInt(columnValue, 10);
    }

    return columnValue;
  },
});
```

```
export async function seedConsumeRecords() {
  console.info('Seeding Consume');
  console.time('seedConsume');
  let records = [];
  let recordsCounter = 0;
  (await open(join(__dirname, 'data/perfil_consumo.csv'), 'r', 0o666))
    .createReadStream()
    .pipe(parser);
  for await (const row of parser) {
    for (const key of Object.keys(row).slice(4)) {
      const obj = {
        codPerfil: row['Cód. Perfil'],
        loggedAt: null,
        value: null,
      };
      obj.loggedAt = new Date(key);
      if (row[key] === '') {
        obj.value = null;
      } else {
        obj.value = parseFloat(row[key]);
      }
      recordsCounter++;
      records.push(obj);
      if (records.length === 5000) {
        console.time('insertDB');
        await prisma.consume.createMany({
          data: records,
          skipDuplicates: true,
        });
        console.timeEnd('insertDB');
        records = [];
      }
    }
  }
  if (records.length > 0) {
    console.time('insertDB');
    await prisma.consume.createMany({
      data: records,
      skipDuplicates: true,
    });
    console.timeEnd('insertDB');
  }
  records = null;
  console.timeEnd('seedConsume');
  const used = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024;
  console.log(
    `The script uses approximately ${Math.round(used * 100) / 100} MB`,
  );
  console.info(`${recordsCounter} records inserted`);
}
```

And at my seed.ts file:

```
async function main() {
  await seedTarifas();
  await seedPerfis();
  await seedConsumeRecords();
  await seedGenerationRecords();
  await seedPurchaseRecords();
  await seedSalesRecords();
  await seedCompanyRecords();
  await seedPartners();
  await seedUsers();
}
```

So after the `seedConsumeRecords` I start seeing stuff like this:

```
Seeding Generation
seedGeneration: 0.339ms
The script uses approximately 770.64 MB
0 records inserted
```

Seems like the parser lost track of itself and is unable to run, but I have no idea why it is behaving that way.

Comment: I think the parser should only be used on one stream, it should not be re-used for multiple streams. Wrap the code that creates the parser in a method and call that method in your "seed" methods.

Comment: I just did it and it solved my issue, I wonder now why the parser is unable to be re-used.

Comment: I'm not sure about the internals of the CSV library, but in general a stream can only be read one time. The parser is a stream which is why you can "pipe" another stream into it.